# postgresql lef join doesn't works

Tags: postgresql, left-join

I would like to add to the table A all the column of the table B, doing a join based on a common column (type numeric). I am trying to do it using the LEFT JOIN but the columns added are all blank. this is impossible because table b stores, among others, the same ID values . Where I am wrong?

```
Select * from "2017_01" left join "Registry_2017" on '2017_01.ID' = 'Registry_2017.ID';
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with postgres, however in most SQL languages entries inside single quotes are treated as strings.  You're likely joining on two different strings rather than two columns.

Comment: Yes!!! You are right, it works now. Thank you very much!

Comment: `'2017_01.ID' = 'Registry_2017.ID'` is a condition that is always false because those two string constants are not equal.

Comment: A table with names made from data instead of a single table with a column for the data can be an anti-pattern. Tables like the former "pivoted" table are reasonable for final human consumption or sometimes for moving to matrix operators but relational manipulation is way simpler with unpivoted straightforward tables.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong.. I don't know why you can use right for `Table` calling `"2017_01"` and different with this `'2017_01.ID'`..

`'` = Single quote identifies as `String`

`"` = Double quote identifies as `Table or Column` to escape Naming

```
Select 
  * 
From 
  "2017_01" 
  left join "Registry_2017" on '2017_01.ID' = 'Registry_2017.ID';
```

So when you doing this `'2017_01.ID' = 'Registry_2017.ID'` The condition will always become `false` because those 2 different `String` are not equal. `Postgresql` look the condition not as `Table and Column` but `String` because you are using `Single quote`

```
Select 
  * 
from 
  "2017_01" 
   left join "Registry_2017" on "2017_01"."ID" = "Registry_2017"."ID";
```

So the query should be like that.. Even you already got answer and it got work i must tell this..